# Basic JSON formatting using Mule Expression Language

Tags: json, mule, mule-el

When sending POST requests to an address on Slack, the JSON needs to be formatted as such:

```
{"channel": "#testing", "username": "test", "text": "Subject"}
```

Or something of the sort, which is normal. The problem I'm having is really basic, but basically, I need to send some details that are obtained from an email via JSON, something like this:

```
{"channel": "#testing", "username": "#[message.inboundProperties['From']]", "text": "Subject"}
```

And when I log the payload after this, I get:

```
{"channel": "#testing", "username": ""Doe, John" <email@address.com>", "text": "Subject"}
```

And this throws a 500 error code, presumably because it is no longer valid JSON (my guess would be because of the weird quotations, but then if I do something else and do something like this:

```
{"channel": "#testing", "username": "username", "text": "#[message.payload]"}
```

Gives me this:

```
{"channel": "#testing", "username": "username", "text": "email body
", "icon_emoji": ":man_with_turban:"}
```

Which looks valid to me, but does not work (perhaps there's a new line character or something, but even then it's just a character in a string is it not?)

I'm not sure how I could do this properly.

Comment: you can escape double quotes  \" Example text\"

Answer (score 3):

The preferred approach for JSON generation in Mule is to create a datastructure (like a `Map`) and use the `json:object-to-json-transformer` to serialize it as JSON. This takes care of escaping.

If you persist in creating JSON as a string, you need to properly escape the values you inject (for example by using [`escapeJavaScript`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript(java.lang.String))).

Comment: Do you happen to know of any good resources I can look for to figure out how to do this?

Comment: This https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference and that https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-JSONProcessing Learning MEL is recommended anyway so it's time well invested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this page to validate JSON:

https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

```
{"channel": "#testing", "username": "username", "text": "email body", "icon_emoji": ":man_with_turban:"}
```